# SQL Server: conditional trigger on imported Line

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to built a trigger on the `[Catalog]` table in the database `[ReportServer]`.

The idea is: when a a report is published, I would like to test

1. if it is built with a VIP data source, and
2. if it not in the VIP folder, because then it shall be deleted

I do not know how to built such a trigger: the query and most of the other steps are or could work.

Could you help with the query for the last entry into the `[Catalog]` table?

So my process is

```
Create a Trigger when a new line is inserted (a report is published)
as
  if the vip-datasource is used and
     if the vip-folder is not used then
        Do save the wrongpath and
        Do delete the report and
        Do send a mail with information about the wrongpath
```

My PowerShell information from `Get-RsItemReference -Path /VIP-Area/Test-Report` is

```
Name = DataSource1
Reference = /VIP-Area/dsDWH_VIP
ReferenceType = DataSource
```

The `DataSource1` has the Value of 'B5DE8D20-894E-4D38-8340-164A0DE61F0F' in `[Catalog].[ItemID]` and `[DataSource].[Link]`

```
CREATE TRIGGER VIP_Monitor  
ON [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS
    DECLARE 
        @TestPath NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TestDataSource NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @WrongPath NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @TestPath = '/VIP-Area/'
    SET @TestDataSource = 'dsDWH_VIP'

    IF @TestDataSource = (SELECT Cat1.[Name] AS [DatasourceName]
                          FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat1
                          LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[DataSource] AS DS1 ON Cat1.ItemID = DS1.Link
                          LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat2 ON DS1.ItemID = Cat2.ItemID
                          WHERE Cat1.[ItemID] = 'B5DE8D20-894E-4D38-8340-164A0DE61F0F')

        IF @TestPath != (SELECT LEFT(Cat1.[Path], 10) AS [DatasourceName]
                         FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat1
                         LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[DataSource] AS DS1 ON Cat1.[ItemID] = DS1.Link
                         LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat2 ON DS1.[ItemID] = Cat2.[ItemID]
                         WHERE Cat1.[ItemID] = 'B5DE8D20-894E-4D38-8340-164A0DE61F0F')

            SET @WrongPath = (SELECT LEFT(Cat1.[Path], 10) AS [DatasourceName]
                              FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat1
                              LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[DataSource] AS DS1 ON Cat1.[ItemID] = DS1.Link
                              LEFT JOIN  [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat2 ON DS1.[ItemID] = Cat2.[ItemID]
                              WHERE Cat1.[ItemID] = 'B5DE8D20-894E-4D38-8340-164A0DE61F0F')

    DELETE FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS Cat1
    WHERE Cat1.[Name] = ### Inserted Report Name ? ### 

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
            @profile_name = 'Admin',  
            @recipients = 'test@test.de',  
            @body = 'The VIP-Report was built in ' + @WrongPath ,  
            @subject = 'Warning: VIP-Report in false Folder';
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: I just admit, a trigger seems like a really bad place for this. Sound more like they should be constraints. Sending an email from a trigger can be a bad idea too; as if the email fails to send so too will your insert.

Comment: This is a bad idea for many reasons. and your trigger has bugs - as soon as more than one row is returned from any query it will fail. Or if you have an issue sending an email it will fail. Then _any_ insert into that table will fail and rollback. Do not put this into production.

Comment: This is not your schema - you should not attempt to alter it in any fashion as it can cause RS to stop working. And this is a management issue that you should take up with your organization. Hard-coding of ID values is inherently risky - what happens when this special datasource is recreated with a new ID? Or migrated to a new instance? You truncated WrongPath - that will only cause confusion in your email (but you defined it as varchar(max) - why?).

Comment: If the person running the report doesn't have access to the folder the VIP data source is in, they won't be able to run the report anyway. In other words, this can be solved with permissions. I know it's not automatic, but you can see the dependent items in the data source properties. That could be reviewed periodically.